# autofs --timeout option not accurate

Tags: linux, nfs, autofs

I have a simple autofs config where I set the option `--timeout=30` on an indirect mapping.
When I access the unmounted storage via `ll /my/mount/path` and do a `watch -n1 "mount | grep /my/mount/path"` immediately after and stop a timer the mount gets unmounted anywhere from 40 seconds onwards and not 30 seconds.

The more I increase the seconds on the `--timeout` option the more inaccurate it gets and the time for the mount to get unmounted increases further.

What am I missing?

autofs version: `autofs.x86_64     1:5.1.4-102.el8_8.2`

Comment: The network connection is just laggy. Check your network equipment.